# How to display pending orders in Magento dashboard graph

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3.2, dashboard

In my `Magento 2` apps don't display the **pending** orders quantities and **Lifetime Sales**, **Average Order,Tax,Revenue,Shipping** values in the **graph** like they used to.

After some searching around, I figured it only displays "**processing**" (orders that have been invoiced) or "**complete**" orders since showing in charts.

I want to pending order details in graph.

[image]

**Note: in Magento 1 [available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170017/10748606) but not Magento 2 available**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Comment: you want to show pending + processing + complete order's total, QTY and all in this graph Right ?

Comment: yes i want to all data working like screenshot  @KishanSavaliya

Comment: One more question here, You just want to show that data on dashboard or in reports as well ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya i want to dashboard all graph details working expect when processing order like in screenshot red box

Comment: I am not sure but it will update when statistics will refresh and I will work via cron as well as Manually. Have you checked this?

Comment: @RakeshDonga, Please check my answer and let me know if it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create `di.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection" />
</config>
```

Now you need to create one Model file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Collection.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order;

class Collection extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
{
    protected function _prepareSummaryLive($range, $customStart, $customEnd, $isFilter = 0)
    {
        $this->setMainTable('sales_order');
        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        /**
         * Reset all columns, because result will group only by 'created_at' field
         */
        $this->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::COLUMNS);

        // $expression = $this->_getSalesAmountExpression();
        $expression = sprintf('%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)',
            $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_invoiced', 'main_table.base_grand_total'),
            $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_invoiced', 'main_table.base_tax_amount'),
            $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_invoiced', 'main_table.base_shipping_amount'),
            $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_refunded', 0),
            $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_refunded', 0),
            $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_refunded', 0)
        );
        if ($isFilter == 0) {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(
                [
                    'revenue' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                        sprintf(
                            'SUM((%s) * %s)',
                            $expression,
                            $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                        )
                    ),
                ]
            );
        } else {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(['revenue' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $expression))]);
        }

        $dateRange = $this->getDateRange($range, $customStart, $customEnd);

        $tzRangeOffsetExpression = $this->_getTZRangeOffsetExpression(
            $range,
            'created_at',
            $dateRange['from'],
            $dateRange['to']
        );

        $this->getSelect()->columns(
            ['quantity' => 'COUNT(main_table.entity_id)', 'range' => $tzRangeOffsetExpression]
        );

        $this->getSelect()
            ->where('main_table.state NOT IN (?)', array(
                \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_HOLDED,
                \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED)
            );

        $this->getSelect()->order(
                'range',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_ASC
            )->group(
                $tzRangeOffsetExpression
            );

        $this->addFieldToFilter('created_at', $dateRange);

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _calculateTotalsLive($isFilter = 0)
    {
        $this->setMainTable('sales_order');
        $this->removeAllFieldsFromSelect();

        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        /*$baseTaxInvoiced = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_invoiced', 0);
        $baseTaxRefunded = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_refunded', 0);
        $baseShippingInvoiced = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_invoiced', 0);
        $baseShippingRefunded = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_refunded', 0);

        $revenueExp = $this->_getSalesAmountExpression();
        $taxExp = sprintf('%s - %s', $baseTaxInvoiced, $baseTaxRefunded);
        $shippingExp = sprintf('%s - %s', $baseShippingInvoiced, $baseShippingRefunded);*/

        $baseTotalInvoiced    = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_invoiced', 'main_table.base_grand_total'); // This will check if there is no invoice it will calculate based on the grand totals ( so when you generate and invoice u will have no issues with the numbers also )
        $baseTotalRefunded    = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_refunded', 0);
        $baseTaxInvoiced      = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_invoiced', 'main_table.base_tax_amount'); // Same here for taxes
        $baseTaxRefunded      = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_refunded', 0);
        $baseShippingInvoiced = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_invoiced', 'main_table.base_shipping_amount'); // Same here for shipping
        $baseShippingRefunded = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_refunded', 0);

        $revenueExp = sprintf('%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)',
            $baseTotalInvoiced,
            $baseTaxInvoiced,
            $baseShippingInvoiced,
            $baseTotalRefunded,
            $baseTaxRefunded,
            $baseShippingRefunded
        );
        $taxExp = sprintf('%s - %s', $baseTaxInvoiced, $baseTaxRefunded);
        $shippingExp = sprintf('%s - %s', $baseShippingInvoiced, $baseShippingRefunded);

        if ($isFilter == 0) {
            $rateExp = $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_to_global_rate', 0);
            $this->getSelect()->columns(
                [
                    'revenue' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $revenueExp, $rateExp)),
                    'tax' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $taxExp, $rateExp)),
                    'shipping' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $shippingExp, $rateExp)),
                ]
            );
        } else {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(
                [
                    'revenue' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $revenueExp)),
                    'tax' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $taxExp)),
                    'shipping' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $shippingExp)),
                ]
            );
        }

        $this->getSelect()->columns(
            ['quantity' => 'COUNT(main_table.entity_id)']
        )->where('main_table.state NOT IN (?)', array(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_HOLDED,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED)
        );

        return $this;
    }

    public function calculateSales($isFilter = 0)
    {
        $statuses = $this->_orderConfig->getStateStatuses(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED);

        if (empty($statuses)) {
            $statuses = [0];
        }
        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        if ($this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'sales/dashboard/use_aggregated_data',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )
        ) {
            $this->setMainTable('sales_order_aggregated_created');
            $this->removeAllFieldsFromSelect();
            $averageExpr = $connection->getCheckSql(
                'SUM(main_table.orders_count) > 0',
                'SUM(main_table.total_revenue_amount)/SUM(main_table.orders_count)',
                0
            );
            $this->getSelect()->columns(
                ['lifetime' => 'SUM(main_table.total_revenue_amount)', 'average' => $averageExpr]
            );

            if (!$isFilter) {
                $this->addFieldToFilter(
                    'store_id',
                    ['eq' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::ADMIN_CODE)->getId()]
                );
            }
            $this->getSelect()->where('main_table.order_status NOT IN(?)', $statuses);
        } else {
            $this->setMainTable('sales_order');
            $this->removeAllFieldsFromSelect();

            // $expr = $this->_getSalesAmountExpression();

            $expr = sprintf('%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)',
                $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_invoiced', 'main_table.base_grand_total'),
                $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_invoiced', 'main_table.base_tax_amount'),
                $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_invoiced', 'main_table.base_shipping_amount'),
                $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_refunded', 0),
                $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_refunded', 0),
                $connection->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_refunded', 0)
            );

            if ($isFilter == 0) {
                $expr = '(' . $expr . ') * main_table.base_to_global_rate';
            }

            $this->getSelect()->columns(
                ['lifetime' => "SUM({$expr})", 'average' => "AVG({$expr})"]
            )->where(
                'main_table.status NOT IN(?)',
                $statuses
            )->where('main_table.state NOT IN(?)', array(
                \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_HOLDED,
                \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED)
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

After adding above both files Please run below commands once

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After doing above changes you can see your pending orders as well same as Magento 1.

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if this works for you or you'll get any errors then.

Comment: kishan currently i am outside of my work and may be i am sure this is working because you have attached screenshot , Thank you once again!!

Comment: Okay @RakeshDonga, You can ping me if you will get any issues then. :)

Comment: @RakeshDonga, I've made this changes with Magento 2.3.3 version. FYI. Thanks.

Comment: means you have change in coding? i have use magento 2.3.2

Comment: No @RakeshDonga, I'll just inform you that my Magento version was 2.3.3 latest so if you're using lower version then tell me if you'll get any issues there then. otherwise this will work perfect.

Comment: This code will work with M2.3 versions. Not checked with 2.2 versions.

Comment: i will imlement coding now if any problem facing then i will told you..

Comment: Okay sure. I'm available now. you can ping me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101234/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-rakesh-donga).

Comment: Thanks Brother, for accepting my answer and upvote. :)

Comment: Hm, on my Magento 2.3.5-p1 its not working. Can someone confirm? Any ideas what to change?

Comment: @Plastikschnitzer, can you share what errors you're getting there ?

Comment: I found the issue: I needed to add a registration.php and a /etc/module.xml to make the module work. Just with the collection.php and the di.xml you mentioned above was not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

**For Magento version 2.2, 2.3 and latest 2.3.3**

You need to look into the following Model,

```
Magento\vendor\magento\module-reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection.php
```

Search for text **STATE_PENDING** in this file and you will get three search results as below,

```
_prepareSummaryLive() // Prepares the query column list, date range, where condition
_calculateTotalsLive() // Calculates total Sales, tax, shipping and no.of sales WRT above query
calculateSales() // as of now you can ignore this method
```

Inside method **_prepareSummaryLive()** and **_calculateTotalsLive()**

Update the Where condition as per you needs

```
 where(
     'main_table.state NOT IN (?)',
      [\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT, \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_NEW]
 )
```

**List of status is defined in**

The order status Constants are defined in the `Magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order.php`

**Consequences:**

The report may be confusing for the Shop administrator because the Key terms like *Revenue, Shipping and Tax* will be *[currrency]0.0*.

But the quantity count shows the numbers including order pending state.

This is due to Magento calculates the terms like Revenue/Tax, Shipping after it is complete, shipped respectively.

[image]